# Long XHR POST stalls on Android devices using Chrome (HTTP status 408)

Tags: php, android, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

*[Solved.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567507/2692950)* Was caused by a 3rd party app...

I have a strange issue trying to implement file uploads using PHP. If I POST a large payload using XHR, it will very often *but not always* stall on my Android (7.0) device running Chrome (72.0.3626.96). The Android device effectively stops sending the payload for no reason. This is not reproducible on a PC at all, and I don't have any other Android device to test with.

*Update:* I get the same strange behavior using this well-tested XHR upload code from github: https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898

The server is running nginx/1.14.2 with PHP 7.3.14-1~deb10u1 on Raspbian Buster.
Here's is the entire PHP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="prog" style="background:#555;height:30px;"></div>
<script>
function Xhr(addr, arg, fdone, fprog){
    var xhr;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", addr, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {   //call done() when done
        if (fdone && this.readyState == 4) fdone(this.status, this.responseText);
    }
    if (fprog && xhr.upload) {              //call prog() on progress
        xhr.upload.onprogress = fprog; xhr.upload.onload = fprog;
    }
    xhr.send(arg);
}
function prog(e){
    var p = 0;
    if (e.type == "load") p = 1;
    else if (e.lengthComputable) p = e.loaded / e.total;
    progbar.style.width = (p*100) + "%";
}
function done(stat){
    alert(stat);
}

var progbar=document.getElementById("prog");

//sends 5MB of data to itself
Xhr("test1.php", 'x'.repeat(5*1024*1024), done, prog);

</script>
</html>
```

When accessed, it simply sends 5MB of data to the its own address with XHR. PHP simply ignores the incoming data here, for test purposes. A progress bar appears at the top.

**Intended behavior:**
On a PC, the progress bar smoothly goes up to 100% and the done() function receives HTTP status `200`.

**Observed behavior:**
On my Android device in Chrome, the progress bar animation is very choppy and usually goes up past 50% immediately, then goes up very slowly the rest of the way, before stalling entirely. 30 seconds later, when the server drops the connection for inactivity, the done() function receives status `0`, while nginx logs status `408 Request` Timeout to the access log.

Interestingly, the progress bar on the phone goes up way past 50% while the server has received less than 10% of the payload. Also, the faster it goes up immediately when opening the page, the higher the chance that the POST will fail. The POST *does* succeed about 5% of the time, always when progress bar starts out at less than 50% immediately when opening the page!

Any ideas are welcome, I'm really at a loss here...

Below is a packet dump as the server is receiving the POST:

```
(initial handshake)
19:08:06.321379 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [S], seq 2067394220, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10030824 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:08:06.321653 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [S.], seq 2059855015, ack 2067394221, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2173911984 ecr 10030824,nop,wscale 7], length 0
(client GETs test1.php)
19:08:06.325516 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 343, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030824 ecr 2173911984], length 0
19:08:06.328377 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 343, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030824 ecr 2173911984], length 517
19:08:06.328542 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [.], ack 518, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173911991 ecr 10030824], length 0
19:08:06.330067 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [P.], seq 1:149, ack 518, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173911992 ecr 10030824], length 148
(client POSTs test1.php)
19:08:06.336971 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030825 ecr 2173911992], length 0
19:08:06.341623 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [P.], seq 518:561, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 43
(payload send start)
19:08:06.342874 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 561:2009, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.343051 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 2009:3457, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.343238 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 3457:4905, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.343462 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 4905:6353, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.343612 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [.], ack 4905, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173912006 ecr 10030826], length 0
19:08:06.343721 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 6353:7801, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.343871 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 7801:9249, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.344006 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 9249:10697, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030826 ecr 2173911992], length 1448
19:08:06.344245 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [.], ack 10697, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173912006 ecr 10030826], length 0
...
(~200 lines similar suppressed)
19:08:06.436894 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [.], ack 349529, win 3810, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173912099 ecr 10030834], length 0
19:08:06.436962 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 349529:350977, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030834 ecr 2173912076], length 1448
19:08:06.437268 IP cli.54556 > server.https: Flags [.], seq 350977:352425, ack 149, win 347, options [nop,nop,TS val 10030834 ecr 2173912076], length 1448
(client stopped sending to server)
(server sends a reset packet 30sec later)
19:08:38.437081 IP server.https > cli.54556: Flags [R.], seq 149, ack 361094, win 3991, options [nop,nop,TS val 2173944099 ecr 10030834], length 0
(XHR fails with status 0, server logs error 408 to access log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that an old version of NetGuard (2.97) was causing this behavior for *any* large uploads, not just in Chrome.